# How to solve LNK201 error?

Tags: qt, build-error

I am trying to build QT project in VS12. I am using qt_4.8.2 and i done qt installation without any error. However when i build project i got LNK201 external errors.

Here is build log :

```
Build started 24.4.2014 09:48:38.
     1>Project "C:\Users\musa\Documents\Work\Face SDK\NEW SDK\face_sdk-0.1.3-windows-x86-nodata-fixed\face_sdk\example\test_facerec.vcxproj" on node 2 (Build target(s)).
     1>Link:
         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:"..\bin\test_facerec.exe" /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:d:\qt_4.8.2\lib d:\qt_4.8.2\lib\QtXmld4.lib d:\qt_4.8.2\lib\QtGuid4.lib d:\qt_4.8.2\lib\QtCored4.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" .obj\main.obj
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QString::~QString(void)" (__imp_??1QString@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QString::QString(char const *)" (__imp_??0QString@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall QString::toStdString(void)const " (__imp_?toStdString@QString@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QFile::QFile(class QString const &)" (__imp_??0QFile@@QAE@ABVQString@@@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QFile::~QFile(void)" (__imp_??1QFile@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual bool __thiscall QFile::open(class QFlags<enum QIODevice::OpenModeFlag>)" (__imp_?open@QFile@@UAE_NV?$QFlags@W4OpenModeFlag@QIODevice@@@@@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QDomNode & __thiscall QDomNode::operator=(class QDomNode const &)" (__imp_??4QDomNode@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QDomNode::~QDomNode(void)" (__imp_??1QDomNode@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QDomNode __thiscall QDomNode::firstChild(void)const " (__imp_?firstChild@QDomNode@@QBE?AV1@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QDomNode __thiscall QDomNode::nextSibling(void)const " (__imp_?nextSibling@QDomNode@@QBE?AV1@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall QDomNode::isNull(void)const " (__imp_?isNull@QDomNode@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QDomElement __thiscall QDomNode::toElement(void)const " (__imp_?toElement@QDomNode@@QBE?AVQDomElement@@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QDomDocument::QDomDocument(void)" (__imp_??0QDomDocument@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QDomDocument::~QDomDocument(void)" (__imp_??1QDomDocument@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QDomElement __thiscall QDomDocument::documentElement(void)const " (__imp_?documentElement@QDomDocument@@QBE?AVQDomElement@@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall QDomDocument::setContent(class QIODevice *,class QString *,int *,int *)" (__imp_?setContent@QDomDocument@@QAE_NPAVQIODevice@@PAVQString@@PAH2@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QString __thiscall QDomElement::tagName(void)const " (__imp_?tagName@QDomElement@@QBE?AVQString@@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QString __thiscall QDomElement::text(void)const " (__imp_?text@QDomElement@@QBE?AVQString@@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QDomElement::~QDomElement(void)" (__imp_??1QDomElement@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pbio::QtServiceConfig::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@QtServiceConfig@pbio@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
     1>..\bin\test_facerec.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 19 unresolved externals
     1>Done Building Project "C:\Users\musa\Documents\Work\Face SDK\NEW SDK\face_sdk-0.1.3-windows-x86-nodata-fixed\face_sdk\example\test_facerec.vcxproj" (Build target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.38
```

Could you help me how to solve this issue ?

Comment: lib files shouldn't have the full path attached to them. Try to remove that.

Comment: Also, QtCore should be specified BEFORE any other lib

Comment: QtCore already specified before other libs

Comment: @Emiliano I did not understand what you mean about lib files and how to remove that ?

Comment: your link commandline has `d:\qt_4.8.2\lib\QtCored4.lib` instead of `QtCored4.lib`. Also, declare `QtCored4.lib` before other libs

Comment: If you use Qt Creator, there is a section called `General Messages`. There You might find what's wrong with your project.